# Scrapy: Do not crawl links on other domains page

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy

Below id my spider I created to get all links on NecToday.com for example.

```
import socket
import scrapy

from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector

class PropertiesItem(scrapy.Item):
    # Primary fields
    title = scrapy.Field()
    url = scrapy.Field()

class NecSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "NecSpider"
    #allowed_domains = ["nectoday.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://nectoday.com"]

    rules = (
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=(), restrict_xpaths=('//a',)), callback="parse_items", follow= True),
    )

    def parse_items(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        print(response.url)
        item = PropertiesItem()
        item["title"] = response.xpath("//title/text()").extract()
        item["url"] = response.url
        return(item)
```

This code starts to fetch all links present on site. Some of the pages have YouTube links as well. The problem is that once the first YouTube link is crawled, it starts to crawl other YouTube links referenced from the first YouTube link.

I want to crawl the first YouTube link, but no others. YouTube is just example. Tomorrow that can be another site as well. How can this be achieved?

Comment: You can create a rule to match all youtube links without follow.

Comment: it will be only for YouTube / known hosts then. I want all other domain links without follow. If you can put sample code would be great for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not try something along the lines of this:

```
start_urls=["http://nectoday.com"] 

def parse(self, response):
    #parse whatever you need

    for url in response.selector.xpath('//@href').extract():
        if 'youtube.com' in url:
            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_no_follow)
        else:
            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse)

def parse_no_follow(self, response):
    #parse whatever you want and not follow anymore links
```

Answer (score 0):

**This will only be scraping from your allowed domain.**

```
class QuotesSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "your app name"
    n=0

    allowed_domains = ['domain']
    start_urls=['anywebpage']
    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        QuotesSpider.n=QuotesSpider.n+1
        if (len(response.body)>100):

            h = html2text.HTML2Text()
            h.ignore_links = True
            h.ignore_images = True
            h.body_width = 0
            dd = response.body.decode("utf-8")
            init=dd.find("<p>")
        while init>0:
            end = dd.find("</p>", init)
            if end>0:
                o=h.handle(dd[init:end+4]+"\n")
                supersentences=o.split('\n')
```